# CloudRun flask deployment results in 503 error

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I want to deploy a simply Flask app that uses the google bucket. But when I deploy It It results in error 503 - Service Unavailable

Im not sure if I forgot something critical but Im really not sure what Im I doing wrong, so any guidance would be appreciated...

```
import os
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from google.cloud import storage

app = Flask(__name__)

storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/home/hajnyondra/hello-world-1/test22-401315-883f659ea7a6.json')

bucket_name = 'json_uloziste'
BUCKET = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

received_values = []
pocitac = 0

def create_json(json_object, filename):
    blob = BUCKET.blob(filename)
    blob.upload_from_string(
        data=json.dumps(json_object),
        content_type='application/json'
    )
    result = filename + ' upload complete'
    return {'response': result}

def get_json(filename):
    blob = BUCKET.get_blob(filename)
    file_data = json.loads(blob.download_as_string())
    return file_data

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/p', methods=['POST'])
def lol():
    global pocitac, received_values
    received_data = request.form['data']
    print(f'Received data: {received_data}')

    if received_data == '777':  # Fixed the comparison
        pocitac = pocitac + 1
        json_data = json.dumps(received_values)
        create_json(json_data, "RUN" + str(pocitac))
        received_values = []
    
    else:
        received_values.append(float(received_data))

    return "nazdar"

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    return jsonify(received_values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

dockerfile:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

requirements:

```
Flask
requests
gunicorn
google-cloud-storage
debugpy # Required for debugging.
```

I tried to change versions and docker config but It either doesnt deploy at all or it does but every request results in 503 error..

Comment: `received_values` as a global is a really bad idea for a webapp.  You need to include the traceback from your server. A 503 comes with a backend error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, and hopefully!

TL;DR: the reason if that you load your service account key file from a not existing location

```
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/home/hajnyondra/hello-world-1/test22-401315-883f659ea7a6.json')
```

`/home` does not exist, you put your application in `/app` in your container

```
# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
```

---

But, as I said, hopefully, because you implemented a bad (anti) pattern of security.

- (Bad Practice) You does not use service account key file (or in very exceptional cases).
- (Anti pattern) You hard-code a path in your code, especially one related to secrets

It's recommended to use [ADC (Application Default Credential)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc) instead. In fact, does not mention explicitly the credential location and let the Google Cloud client library detect it automatically from the runtime environment.